# my prefix can turn to sand, my suffix is at hand

Tags: riddle, word, language, music, movies

my prefix can turn to sand
my suffix is at hand
my infix is a French end
the whole is a famous movie

Comment: What's the music tag for?

Comment: "Gold can turn to Sand" is a song

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is:

> **GOLDFINGER**

*my prefix can turn to sand*

> ***GOLD** Can Turn to Sand* is a [song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=poMvu9EcyfI).

*my suffix is at hand*

> A **FINGER** is part of a hand.

*my infix is a French end*

> The word '**FIN**' is French for 'end', often seen on-screen at the end of a French film.

*the whole is a famous movie*

> ***[GOLDFINGER](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldfinger_(film))*** is a 1964 James Bond outing for Sean Connery.

Comment: perfect answer!